# Connecting Nfs storage to proxmox cluster

Tags: nfs, proxmox

[When Im trying to add nfs storage from Truenas to my cluster it gives me this error, any ideas how to fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EJs9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has your share been created with no_root_squash option? Check your NFS share options on Truenas and also check the user id (root, anonymous, guest, etc.).

In my experience, the fault often is the wrong root squash option.